# Delimiter issue - Copying Data from Azure SQL to Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory, etl

I am trying to load data from Azure SQL to Snowflake. I am under the constraint to use the copy activity only.
I am using a lookup table to reference a metadata table with the source schema, source tables, target schema, and target tables.
I am then using a For Each Activity to iterate through the metadata table.
I’m using two copy activities inside of that - one to move the data from SQL to Blob and the other to move the data from Blob to Snowflake. I am getting an error « « Found character C instead of delimiter ‘,’ «. I have tried using different delimiters but my data consists of those characters.
Is there a way to resolve this, in a way to use a specific file format on the snowflake end before the copy activity takes place( cannot write a script as the storage account is in West US2 and Snowflake account is in East US2).

Any help is greatly appreciated!!!!

Thank you.

Tried using different delimiters.

Comment: can you share sample data?

Comment: Dose this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72793461) helped you?

Answer (score 0):

Copy data to/from Snowflake takes advantage of Snowflake's COPY into command.

If you check in the the Copy Activity (Blob to Snowflake)

In Sink Tab: You would find :

- Additional Snowflake Copy Options
- Additional Snowflake format options

[addtional options in ADF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g03tu.png)

You could click on the + Symbol to add these options.

Additional copy options, provided as a dictionary of key-value pairs. Examples: ON_ERROR, FORCE, LOAD_UNCERTAIN_FILES.

Additional file format options provided to the COPY command, provided as a dictionary of key-value pairs. Examples: DATE_FORMAT, TIME_FORMAT, TIMESTAMP_FORMAT.

For more information, check below links.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html#copy-options-copyoptions
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html#format-type-options-formattypeoptions

In your case you could add below in your Additional Snowflake format options:

FIELD_DELIMITER = ''

Also check out this option

FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = 'character'  ,if needed for your use-case.

For detailed documentation of Snowflake Connector in ADF, refer to this :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-snowflake?tabs=data-factory

Comment: Didn't help. The inputs are simply being ignored